# Javascript: How do I get the height of unloaded images in a loop?

Tags: javascript, onload

I am loading a json file and parsing it into an array in Javascript. One of the elements is the path to an image. I am not ready to load the images yet but I need to get the image's height. I know how to do that with code like the following (found on other stackoverflow pages)

```
function getimageheight(img) {
    var tmpImg = new Image();
    tmpImg.onload = function() {
        var ht = this.height;   
        return ht+0;
    }
    tmpImg.src = img;
}
```

If I try to call this function in a loop, it returns undefined because the onload for the images is running slower than the loop. My actual code is this:

```
        var j = 0;
        $.each(cat.placemarks, function(index, mark) {
            markers[cat.name][j] = [];
            markers[cat.name][j].name = mark.name;
            markers[cat.name][j].title = mark.title;
            markers[cat.name][j].markerURL = mark.markerURL;
            markers[cat.name][j].imageURL = mark.imageURL;
            markers[cat.name][j].imageHEIGHT = getimageheight(projpath+mark.imageURL);
            j++;
        });
```

If I call the function once, it works.  But calling it in a loop does not. How can I fix this?

Comment: I could be misreading something, but I'm baffled that you say it's working when you call the function once. Your `getImageHeight()` function isn't returning anything. The return value from your `onload()` function isn't going anywhere, certainly not back to the code that called `getImageHeight()`. You can't get the height of an image that isn't loaded. Your `onload` function can get the height only because it runs **after** the image is loaded.

Comment: If I 'alert(ht)' right before the return, it displays the correct value. Why doesn't it return it?

Comment: Looks like you've gotten some other feedback, but just in case you still have this question, consider: `load(function() { /* do stuff */ } )` doesn't cause `/* do stuff */` to occur when you call `load()`. It causes `/* do stuff */` to occur *when the image is finished loading*. Someone mentioned asynchronous execution in another comment. Look into that. In javascript you have to think in terms of starting one thing happening, exiting the function that started that thing, and then being awakened again in another function once that thing is completed.

Comment: Also note that when you do `tmpImg.onload = function()...` you're not calling that function. You're setting `.onload` equal to that function, which tells the browser to call that function *on load*, ie, when the image is loaded.

Comment: Yes, I learned that. I see now it is a problem of scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store reference to data object in Img object used to load it, you can set the value of its properties after the loading is done. Hope that makes sense... Your data will not be ready to use before loading is complete tho. Heres the code

```
var total=cat.placemarks.length;//if an array, otherwise use another each cycle to get object count
var loaded=0;

$each(cat.placemarks, function(index, mark) {
    markers[cat.name][j] = [];

    var tmpImg = new Image();
    tmpImg.refToObjWithNameOfYourChoice=markers[cat.name][j];
    tmpImg.onload = function() {
        this.refToObjWithNameOfYourChoice.imageHEIGHT=this.heigh;
        loaded++;
        if(loaded==total){
            //markers data is ready to use - add function callback herer or sumthin'
        }
    }
    tmpImg.src=projpath+mark.imageURL;

    markers[cat.name][j].name = mark.name;
    markers[cat.name][j].title = mark.title;
    markers[cat.name][j].markerURL = mark.markerURL;
    markers[cat.name][j].imageURL = mark.imageURL;
    j++;

});
```

Comment: Ahhh. I see. Put the load inline AND the assignment to the array. I just have to be aware that the full array won't be available for a short bit. That should work.

Comment: Probably not the prettiest code but gets the job done. Full array will be available instantly, its just that imageHeight property for its elements wont be set until loading of according images is done. Are you familiar with asynchronous execution?

Comment: Somewhat, that's why I knew this was a problem. :)

Comment: I still can't get this to work. I tried moving the  markers[cat.name][j] = []; to before the tmpImg declaration but that didn't help. Even long after this runs the markers[cat.name][j].imageHEIGHT value is undefined. (of course, j is long gone by then, I am just using it as a reference point.)

Comment: Best advice i can give at this point is to open debugger in browser and add breakpoint somewhere in onload function. See how everything looks. j does not matters.

Answer (score 0):

`markers[cat.name][j].imageHEIGHT` is undefined because `getImageHeight()` isn't returning anything. And naturally, the image load will occur much more slowly than your `each()` loop, so it won't do you any good to have `getImageHeight()` return something. You'll have to set up your `load()` callback to determine which image has been loaded and update the height of the corresponding `markers` element.

Comment: Why doesn't it return? The return is inside the onload function so it should return AFTER the load. But my problem is the calling code continues before this value comes back.

Comment: @DougWolfgram you have TWO functions here, getimageheight and the onload function. The latter returns the height, but the former returns nothing.

Comment: oh crap. I see... doh!